# Search data field by year in Janusgraph

Tags: date, gremlin, janusgraph

I have a 'Date' property on my 'Patent' node class that is formatted like this:

```
==>Sun Jan 28 00:08:00 UTC 2007
==>Tue Jan 27 00:10:00 UTC 1987
==>Wed Jan 10 00:04:00 UTC 2001
==>Sun Jan 17 00:08:00 UTC 2010
==>Tue Jan 05 00:10:00 UTC 2010
==>Thu Jan 28 00:09:00 UTC 2010
==>Wed Jan 04 00:09:00 UTC 2012
==>Wed Jan 09 00:12:00 UTC 2008
==>Wed Jan 24 00:04:00 UTC 2018
```

And is stored as `class java.util.Date` in the database.

Is there a way to search this field to return all the 'Patents' for a particular year?

I tried variations of `g.V().has("Patent", "date", 2000).values()`. However, it doesn't return any results or an error message.

Is there a way to search this property field by year or do I need to create a separate property that just contains year?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a separate property for the year. JanusGraph recognizes the `Date` data type and can filter by date values.

```
gremlin> dateOfBirth1 = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 5, 6).getTime()
==>Tue Jun 06 00:00:00 MDT 2000
gremlin> g.addV("person").property("name", "Person 1").property("dateOfBirth", dateOfBirth1)
==>v[4144]
gremlin> dateOfBirth2 = new GregorianCalendar(2001, 5, 6).getTime()
==>Wed Jun 06 00:00:00 MDT 2001
gremlin> g.addV("person").property("name", "Person 2").property("dateOfBirth", dateOfBirth2)
==>v[4328]
gremlin> dateOfBirthFrom = new GregorianCalendar(2000, 0, 1).getTime()
==>Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 MST 2000
gremlin> dateOfBirthTo = new GregorianCalendar(2001, 0, 1).getTime()
==>Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 MST 2001
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").
......1> has("dateOfBirth", gte(dateOfBirthFrom)).
......2> has("dateOfBirth", lt(dateOfBirthTo)).
......3> values("name")
==>Person 1
```